# How to update a key/value using jq

Tags: jq

I have a key/value below in a JSON

```
JAVA_OPTS="JAVA_OPTS": "-Xms1g -Xmx2g -Dapi.version=v1 -Dspring.profiles.active=test -Dservice.name=xyz"
```

Using jq i want to insert one more string to this key/value pair `"-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2"`

So the output should looks like

```
JAVA_OPTS="JAVA_OPTS": "-Xms1g -Xmx2g -Dapi.version=v1 -Dspring.profiles.active=test -Dservice.name=xyz -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2"
```

Comment: That's not json...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for something like that :

```
jq '.JAVA_OPTS |= . + " -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2"'
```

[Try it here](https://jqplay.org/s/9_01xLwOTv).